# this is a cards game and i have a brace enclosed error

Tags: c++

i check which player has a bigger value card.... then i print his name in the main function...but then comes an error

(the error is in output [ n ] line  : cannot convert '' to 'char' in assignment)

```
void CardsGamePlay(int samy[], int magdy[], int n, char output[])
{

    int max1, max2 = 0;

    //comparing the card numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (samy[i] > max1)
        {
            max1 = samy[i];
        }
        if (magdy[i] > max2)
        {
            max2 = magdy[i];
        }
    }
    if (max1 > max2)
    {

        output[n] = {'s', 'a', 'm',  'y', 0};
    }
    else if (max1 < max2)
    {
       output[n] = {'m', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'y', 0};

    }
    else
    {
        output[n] = {'d', 'r', 'a', 'w', 0};
    }
}
```

```
int main()

{

    int samy[] = {2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 4}, magdy[] = {5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4};

    char output[6];


    CardsGamePlay(samy, magdy, 6, output);


    cout << output << endl; // This line should print: Samy

}
```

Comment: Why do you try to write a C style solution? Why don't you use `std::string` which is easier and safer? Also don't pass C style arrays, use `std::array` so you always have the size information.

Comment: All of the `output[n] = {'m', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'y', 0};` are a bugs.  Using output[6] is trying to add data 1 past the end of the array.

Comment: im still in first year of college and this is the only syntax i know @WernerHenze

Comment: You should use reference variables to pass them into parameters of the function and change their values (the value "output" is unchanged and left to be blank as soon as it goes out of CardsGamePlay().

Comment: i should use & in the cardgame function then ?  @LinuXMan

Comment: That won't fix the problem. output is not passed by value anyways. And that is not even the problem.

Comment: you are right .. i tried that @drescherjm

Comment: You can only use this symtax `output[n] = {'m', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'y', 0};` when you are declaring a new variablelike this `char output[6] = {'m', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'y', 0};`. It does not work as an assignment. c arrays are not assignable. Also putting the `char` before `output` will not fix your problem.

Comment: oh ok ... if i cant assign anything to the output array , then how can i change the name everytime a condition happens ? maybe with for loops ? @drescherjm

Comment: You could use a for loop. You could use one of the c string functions that copy c-strings.

Comment: `output[n] = {'s', 'a', 'm',  'y', 0};` is wrong twice - can't assign all those chars (use strcpy() or a for loop) and you are not using your iterator index `i`, but the size `n` which is bad on many levels.

Comment: Is this for a C class assignment and not C++?

Comment: ^ The if ()  is not inside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Instead for char[] use, std::string, much simple

#include<string>

void CardsGamePlay(int samy[], int magdy[], int n, std::string &sName)
{

    int max1, max2 = 0;

    //comparing the card numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (samy[i] > max1)
        {
            max1 = samy[i];
        }
        if (magdy[i] > max2)
        {
            max2 = magdy[i];
        }
    }
    if (max1 > max2)
    {

        sName = "Samy";
    }
    else if (max1 < max2)
    {
       sName = "Magdy";

    }
    else
    {
        sName = "Draw";
    }
}

int main()

{

    int samy[] = {2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 4}, magdy[] = {5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4};

   std::string sName;


    CardsGamePlay(samy, magdy, 6, sName);


    cout << output << endl; 

}
```

Comment: sorry but im obligated to the syntax i provided in the question ... i cant use another

Comment: in that case use : output[] = {'m', 'a', 'g', 'd', 'y','0'}; and when output using cout  use below: for (int i =0; i<6; i++) cout<<output[i];

Comment: if your are satisfied with answer please mark it as answer

Comment: @AhmedMagdi from my gesture, the question was just asked for character arrays, not strings, it was also mentioned by user9559196. What's wrong in my updated code? I made the code relevant to your requirement.

Comment: the thing is i cant modify in the main function too ..this maybe  my problem not saying that from the begining in the title ... in your code all the work was in the main function so i cant take it besides that i know nothing about std:: syntax either @LinuXMan

Comment: "std::" is just a prefix which is equivalent to direct statements after "using namespace std;". But keeping using std prefixes is a good programming practice. No problems if that didn't work for you.

Comment: ok sir i will  keep that in mind ..and  thank you so much for trying to help @LinuXMan

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your expectations in a better manner. Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

char CardsGamePlay(int[], int[], int);

int main(void) {
    int samy[] = {2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 4}, magdy[] = {5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4};
    int max1, max2;
    char final;

    max1 = max2 = 0;

    short int size = sizeof(samy) / sizeof(samy[0]); // gets array size
    final = CardsGamePlay(samy, magdy, size); // function call

    if (final == 's') // comparison
        std::cout << "Samy wins." << std::endl; // max1 > max2
    else if (final == 'm')
        std::cout << "Magdy wins." << std::endl; // max1 < max2
    else
        std::cout << "Draw." << std::endl; // max1 == max2

    return 0;
}

char CardsGamePlay(int samy[], int magdy[], int n)
{
    int max1, max2; // initialization
    max1 = max2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (samy[i] > max1)
            max1 = samy[i]; // setting maximum for Samy
        if (magdy[i] > max2)
            max2 = magdy[i]; // setting maximum for Magdy
    }

    if (max1 == max2)
        return 'd'; // draw? yes: exit with "draw" no: keep going till last

    return (max1 > max2) ? 's' : 'm'; // used ?: operator; s = samy, m = magdy
}
```

A function is written which iterates till it reaches the array size of Samy (which is equal to Magdy in your program) and sets two max values. Then finally it returns a character expression which determines who wins when it's called in the main function.

Hope it helps you understanding better.

Comment: I thought you said in the other answer that you could not use `std::string`

Comment: @drescherjm why using character arrays in C++ if there's already a better option...

Comment: Of course but academic institutions often teach new students `c` and call it a `c++`class.

Comment: actually i said so but nothing i can do about...it seems like the only way @drescherjm

Comment: I told you how to do it without `std::string`. Here is a tutorial: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcpy-in-c-cpp/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcpy-in-c-cpp/)

Comment: @drescherjm I've updated the code, now **without std::string**.